# Pre-select the Multiselect options matching db values

Tags: php, multi-select, selected

I am creating a customer account page which displays the information in the database and allows customers to edit their information. The code below shows the relevant option as selected when there is only one value in the associated db column, but it stops pre-selecting values when there is more than one value in the column and therefore isn't working for the multi-select elements on the page.

How can I modify `if($row1['notifications']=='New_Items')` so that it will work when more than one value has been selected? Adding square brackets `['notifications[]']=='New_Items'` throws the error message `"Notice: Undefined index notifications[]"` and prevents any values from being pre-selected.

The multi-select form elements are structured as name="element_name[]" and are inserted into the database as arrays, and arrays `implode` when they're inserted. When values are fetched, I'm using `str_replace` to strip the commas after each option so that it can properly compare the value to the option's value *(there doesn't seem to be a need to explode the values)*

```
<?php   
try {  
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer_info WHERE user_id = :user_id");  
$stmt->bindValue(':user_id', $user_id); 
$stmt->execute();
}catch(PDOException $e) {echo $e->getMessage();}
$row = $stmt->fetch();
$row1 = str_replace(',', '', $row);
?>
<form action="account_information-exec.php" method="post">
    <select name="notifications[]" multiple="multiple" >            
    <option value="New_Items" <?php if($row1['notifications']=='New_Items') echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>New items</option>           
    <option value="Sale_Items" <?php if($row1['notifications']=='Sale_Items') echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Sale items</option>
    </select>  
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

account_information-exec.php *- File which Inserts and/or Updates DB*

```
<?php
require_once "config/config.php"; // Connects to db 
$user_id = $_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID'];   
try {        
$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO customer_info (user_id, notifications) 
VALUES(:user_id, :notifications)                  
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE notifications = :notifications2');    
    function bindMultiple($stmt, $params, &$variable, $type) {
    foreach ($params as $param) {
        $stmt->bindParam($param, $variable, $type);
        }
    } 
    $stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);    
    bindMultiple($stmt, array(':notifications', ':notifications2'), implode(',', $_POST['notifications']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
} catch(PDOException $e) {echo $e->getMessage();}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume $row1['notifications'] is stored as a concatenated string of selected values. If so, try this instead:

```
if(strpos($row1['notifications'], 'New_Items') >= 0)
```

Note that you should account for delimiters (not sure why you're stripping the comma, is there a space left?).

Comment: I don't believe that it's being stored as a concatenated string (unless the implode function does that in account_information-exec.php ?). The reason I'm stripping the commas is so that it can properly compare the value to the option's value (otherwise it was reading the comma as a character)